# How to remove dead methods from a very large solution/project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How does One remove All the Dead Methods (i.e. Methods which are not not in use in the Project or Solution) from a very Large Visual Studio Solution.

Comment: Use Resharper.  It can do this.  Code Maid *might* be able to, I've never used it.

Comment: Thanx Amy. Will try. I have Resharper. Can Resharper Help in Removing all the Comments also, in a Project/Solution.

Comment: Maybe.  That sounds like it would fall under Resharper's Cleanup tool.  (I'm at home, but have Resharper at work, so I can't be more specific, sorry.)  Comments are generally desirable though.

Comment: Why would you want to remove all of the comments?

Comment: @mjwills actually you are right. I don't think removing comments is essential. I had a thought about How in HTML code for a website Page, the Comments can be seen in the Source of the Webpage within the browser. So I thought on the same lines, that if someone reverse engineers your Dll's, he might be able to see your comments too. But i guess the Compiler itself would not include the comments in its output Dll.

Comment: Comments are not included in compiled binaries.

Comment: thanx @Amy. that is an important info.